# I know there's a better way but I don't see it. Parsing out sub urls

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops

Any ideas on how to turn this list

```
// How to get from this urls
[
     '/this',
     '/should/not',
     '/should/close',
     '/should',
     '/not/be/that',
     '/this/is'
]
```

Into this structure?

```
// To this in a smart way
[
    {
        url: 'this',
        sub: [{
            url: 'is'
        }]
    },
    {
        url: 'should',
        sub: [{
            url: 'not'
        },{
            url: 'close'
        }]
    },
    {
        url: 'not',
        sub: [{
            url: 'be',
            sub: [{
                url: 'hard'
            }]
        }]
    }
]
```

I'm not asking becouse of speed and I've already got a running solution (using for-loop iterating once over the first level, then over the next level, etc and building up the results) but keep thinking that there should be possible to do this with just a few lines of code.

Is it?

Larsi

Comment: Is there a child more beautiful than my daughter? You can't say, because you haven't seen my daughter. Also, this is off topic.

Comment: Do you really have to have that structure? The array in the resulting element really makes it a pain to format.

Comment: yes, agree that it's a pain format. But it need to be like that. And based on votes to close and nobody posting a clever one-liner I guess I 'll leave my code as is, and just forget about this problem :-)

Comment: Ai...! I'm very sorry Cerbrus. The sub is an array, my example does not indicate that. I'll update it

Comment: Aaaargh! it's even worse than I feared xD
Can you elaborate as to why the format can't change?

Comment: Sure. I've got an angular app that emulates a sharepoint website. The model is currently bind to this structure, and this structure is also converted to xml and used by powershell for scripting site. So to change format I need update angular app, and powershell scripts.

Comment: mohem  and @cerbrus. Thanks for providing suggestions. I see that my question was not a good fit for SO, so I'll vote to close my own question.

Answer (score 1):

I have this "solution", in case you could use a different format:

```
var a = [
     '/this',
     '/should/not',
     '/should',
     '/not/be/that',
     '/this/is'
],
b = {};

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    var items = a[i].replace('/','').split('/');
    var temp = {};
    b[items[0]] = temp;
    for(var j = 1; j < items.length; j++){
        temp[items[j]] = {};
        temp = temp[items[j]];
    }
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "this": {
        "is": {}
    },
    "should": {},
    "not": {
        "be": {
            "that": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving a try! Unfortunatly the format cannot change.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Cerbrus that the proposed structure is horrible, but here's an attempt:

```
    var dir = [
         '/this',
         '/should/not',
         '/should',
         '/not/be/that',
         '/this/is'
    ];

    var res = [];

    function subify(s) {
        if (s == "") return {url: ""};
        if (s[0] == "/") s = s.substr(1);

        var i = s.indexOf("/", 0);

        if (i < 0) return {url: s}
        return {url: s.substr(0, i), sub: subify(s.substr(i + 1))};            
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < dir.length; i++) {
        var s = subify(dir[i]);            // create object
        if ("sub" in s) res.push(s);       // filter out non-subs
    }
```

You might be able to get closer to a one-liner with some fancy regular-expression replacement. This code will work on paths like yours, but not if there are trailing slashes. It will also not enforce that ther is a slash at the beginning; that information will be lost.

Comment: I'm only getting `{url:"this", sub:{url:"is"}}` out of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did a minor error writing the example, so your code not correct. Sorry for wasting your time :-(

Comment: @Cerbrus: Hmm, I get the three entries with more than one slash when I print to the console. But my code can't handle the new (edited) requirement anyway, so I'll just let it stand.

Comment: @Larsi: I see; the updated data structure is even uglier than the one before. Since you already seem to have a solution, I'll let it stand.

Answer (score 0):

You could try some recursive mapping algorithm:

```
function mapurl (a){
  var aa = a.replace(/^\//,'').split('/'), obj = {url: aa[0]};
  if (aa.length>1) { 
    var x= [];  
    mapurl.call(x, aa.slice(1).join('/')); 
    obj.sub = x; 
  }
  this.push( obj );
  return a;
}
var urls2objs = [];
[
 '/this',
 '/should/not',
 '/should/close',
 '/should',
 '/not/be/that',
 '/this/is'
].map(mapurl, urls2objs);
//=> now urls2objs contains an array of objects 
     ( [{url: ...,  sub: [{url:..., sub:...}] }
```

Comment: Except that this creates duplicate entries for `"should"` and `"this"`

Comment: @Cerbrus: really? http://testbed.nicon.nl/img/somapurls.jpg

Comment: Yea, really. It's more visible when you [**don't expand** the sub elements](http://static.dyp.im/CoPSl0sPGO/e4a678a725418bec82b7a129d8def329.PNG), or as [**JSON**](http://static.dyp.im/qe9jO4yG6h/9082a54eb69f5beb4e26ad354c209cf2.PNG).

Comment: Well, it's just mapping what it encounters within the array, and the answer just aims at giving a direction. Maybe `reduce` could be the next step here to combine urls.